# Cpp predefined structs?

Tags: c#, c++, struct

Last time I used C++ was when I attended university, therefor I am not very fluent in it.

I wanted to create a small game, and because I am used to C# I wanted to create predefinded struct objects.

Here is the C# code for reference:

```cs
public struct Vector2 : IEquatable<Vector2>
{

  private static readonly Vector2 _zeroVector = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
  private static readonly Vector2 _unitVector = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
  private static readonly Vector2 _unitXVector = new Vector2(1f, 0.0f);
  private static readonly Vector2 _unitYVector = new Vector2(0.0f, 1f);

  [DataMember]
  public float X;
  [DataMember]
  public float Y;

  public static Vector2 Zero => Vector2._zeroVector;
  public static Vector2 One => Vector2._unitVector;
  public static Vector2 UnitX => Vector2._unitXVector;
  public static Vector2 UnitY => Vector2._unitYVector;

  public Vector2(float x, float y)
  {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
  }
}
```

In C# I could now use this code to get a Vector with x = 0 and y = 0

```cs
var postion = Vector2.Zero;
```

Is there a way to create something like this in C++ or do I have to life with the basicness of c++ and use a struct like this?

```cpp
struct Vector2 {
    float x, y;
    Vector2(float x, float y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};
```

Comment: Adding `static const Vector2 Zero;` doesn't do the trick for you? How about adding the `static consteval Vector2 Zero();` function in the class?

Comment: OMG, looks like my brain was turned off for a moment,. Thank you very much and sorry for asking a stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, with recent versions of C++, you can simplify your struct definition like this:

```
struct Vector2 {
    float x{}, y{};
};
```

This guarantees that x and y are initialized with 0, you don't need the separate constructor as you show it. You can then use the struct like this:

```
Vector2 myVec;  // .x and .y are set to 0
myVec.x = 1; myVec.y = 2;
```

You can even use what's called an "initializer list" to create a struct with predefined values for x and y instead of the default 0, like this:

```
Vector2 myVec2{1,2};
```

Regarding your need for "global" instances of your Vector2 struct, you can make use of the `static` keyword in C++ similarly as in C#:

```
struct Vector2 {
    float x{}, y{};
    static const Vector2 Zero;
    static const Vector2 Unit;
    static const Vector2 UnitX;
    static const Vector2 UnitY;
};
```

In contrast to C++, you cannot specify the value of constant(s) directly in the class though (if you try you get an `incomplete type` error, since at the time when the compiler encounters the constant, the class definition is not complete yet); you need to "define" the constant(s) somewhere outside your class:

```
const Vector2 Vector2::Zero{};
const Vector2 Vector2::Unit{1.0f, 1.0f};
const Vector2 Vector2::UnitX{1.0f, 0.0f};
const Vector2 Vector2::UnitY{0.0f, 1.0f};
```

While the above `struct Vector2 ...` typically goes somewhere in a .h file to be included by multiple other files, the definition should go into a .cpp file, and not in the header, otherwise you will get multiply defined symbol errors.

Comment: You're basically recommending a personal preference here. The presence or absence of constructors in a struct imho doesn't make it "awkward". The same effect could be achieved by adding default values to the constructor parameters without one being objectively better (at least prior to C++20, but you don't address this). You don't really address the core of the question however: The OP wants to know if doing something like `var postion = Vector2.Zero;` is possible (which is the case), but there's not a single sentence about this in the answer.

Comment: I was getting to that ;) but yes got carried away and probably very off-topic, sorry about that, and thanks for the detailed comment!

Answer (score 1):

I might have a solution but I am not sure.

Vector2.h

```cpp
struct Vector2 {
    static const Vector2 Zero;
    static const Vector2 One;
    float x {}, y {};
}
```

Vector2.cpp

```cpp
#include "Vector2.h"

const Vector2 Vector2::Zero = Vector2 {0, 0};
const Vector2 Vector2::One = Vector2 {1, 1};
```